# Can I force a Sharepoint template behave like HTML frames?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, page-layout

I have a template consisting of two columns...a left sidebar and a wide column. I would like to load a document index into the left sidebar--an easy enough view to design--but my challenge is the main window. I want the main window to bring up the new document WITHOUT refreshing the whole page.

Basically, if I click on "Letter A" in the index, Letter A pops up on the right side of the page WITHOUT the rest of the page refreshing. Move to "Letter B" and letter B does that same...

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery? Ajax maybe?

Comment: Sounds like AJAX to me.

Comment: Is this a document you want to appear in the right hand side? If it's just a list there is a format of list View called 'Preview' that might work for you.

Comment: I've tried Preview already, @AndyBurns. However, on my end, the view is a list of the chosen metadata...not the document content. Is there a switch for this somewhere? This sounds exactrly like what I need...and it's simple. :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's what I meant by 'if it's just a a list'. No, I'm not aware of a general way of doing that. After all, the document could be any arbitrary file type - e.g. .doc, .pdf, .zip, .raw, .mp3 ... etc.. I think jQuery or a custom web part might be the way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you could achieve it by combining the Page Viewer Web Part with jQuery changing the iFrame properties.

C:\Marius